# Force magento to use full product path in all pages

Tags: category-products

I need to force magento to use only full product paths with categories and subcategories. Can i somehow achieve it? I enabled "Use category paths to product urls", reindexed everything but no result.. From home page or any category i can enter only product with url: website.com/product.html

Am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: You said you reindexed everything but did you clear the cache?

Comment: I have disabled cache because website is currently in development.
So i cleared cache anyway but no result.

Comment: Ok. The url like you described website.com/product.html has to exist since magento sets canonical-url for seo purposes from every other link of that specific product to website.com/product.html - otherwise you would have a lot of duplicated content. That you have such links on homepage is "normal" since there the product is in no category but on homepage. That you have that at categories seems strange to me. Are the products accessable if you type in the url with categories in path?

Comment: @StefanGregori Yes it is accessible in both ways. Maybe it can be possible, when i imported categories magento made all of categories Anchor? Maybe that's why?

Comment: As far as I know this should not be the problem. For me this looks like the developer of your theme didnt use the correct product collection and didnt use the correct function to get and add the product url at your category-template.

Comment: Ok. I will write to template support. Thanks for help.

Comment: No Problem. Just add another comment if I can help any further! Good luck. And please dont forget to post the answer yourself if you can fix it so that others can use it!!!